# Assigning the order of a list using a defined rule

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a predefined list containing a rule for a specified sorting:

```py
lst = ['d', 'a', 't', 'b', 'r']
```

And I have a dictionary on which I iterate to get its values.

```py
dictionary = {}
dictionary[0] = ['t', 45]
dictionary[1] = ['b', 65]
dictionary[2] = ['r', 52]
dictionary[3] = ['a', 14]
dictionary[4] = ['d', 4]
```

I want to specify that every "first" element of each value from the dictionary is within the starting list.

I need to populate a new list by adding every "second" element (i.e. the numbers) in the specific position ruled by the first list. More in detail, doing something in this loop:

```py
newList = []
for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
    # Do what?
```

I need to obtain this:

```py
newList = [4, 14, 45, 65, 52]
```

Comment: While storing the data in `dict`, why are you having keys as: 0, 1, 2.. instead of making the keys as: "d", "a", "t"..? Secondly, in your code, it should be: `iteritems()` i.e `()` instead of `[]`

Comment: It's an example, the keys of the dictionary are the ids from an object. In other words, I need to do something only on the values from the dictionary (using a dict(zip) on it could be an idea?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just build and use the proper dictionary:

```
>>> map(dict(dictionary.values()).get, lst)
[4, 14, 45, 65, 52]
```

But you should probably really not structure your dictionary your way but directly use `dictionary = {'t': 45, 'b': 65, 'r': 52, 'a': 14, 'd': 4}`. Then it would be simply this:

```
>>> map(dictionary.get, lst)
[4, 14, 45, 65, 52]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create a dictionary based on the values of current dictionary as:

```
dictionary = {
    0: ['t', 45],
    1: ['b', 65],
    2: ['r', 52],
    3: ['a', 14],
    4: ['d', 4]
}

values_dict = dict(dictionary.values())
```

In order to get the desired result, you may use *list comprehension* to extract values based on above `dict` as:

```
lst = ['d', 'a', 't', 'b', 'r']
new_list = [values_dict[k]  for k in lst]
```

where the content hold by `new_list` will be:

```
[4, 14, 45, 65, 52]
```

*Note:* The element at 0th index of all the values in the initial * dictionary* dict should be unique.

Comment: `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: @mgri Which version of Python? Working on Python 2.7

Comment: Works on Python 3.4 as well. You must be doing something wrong

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.4

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri The version where they overwrote the builtin `dict`.

Comment: I used `dict` many other times without any problem. I'm going to understand what it's wrong.

Comment: As mentioned by Stefan, you have override the `dict` somewhere in you code

Comment: @mgri youve overwritten the built-in `dict` function with an actuall dictionary, someting like `dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Many thanks, the code now works! However, I'll accept the other answer because is a one-line solution.